# Make a new column panda from a string. Do I need some kind of iterable?

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, so this works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ind = [0,1,2]
d = {'col1' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 'col2' : pd.Series([5, 6, 7, 8],  index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 'col3' : pd.Series([9, 10, 11, 12], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

gives the following:

```
   col1  col2  col3
a     1     5     9
b     2     6    10
c     3     7    11
d     4     8    12
```

to add a column using math, this works:

```
df['new'] = df['col2'] + df['col3']
```

which gives:

```
   col1  col2  col3  new
a     1     5     9   14
b     2     6    10   16
c     3     7    11   18
d     4     8    12   20
```

BUT THIS DOESNT WORK:

```
df['new2'] = str(df['col3'])
```

if gives this, which is weird:

```
   col1  col2  col3  new                                             new2
a     1     5     9   14  a     9\nb    10\nc    11\nd    12\nName: col3...
b     2     6    10   16  a     9\nb    10\nc    11\nd    12\nName: col3...
c     3     7    11   18  a     9\nb    10\nc    11\nd    12\nName: col3...
d     4     8    12   20  a     9\nb    10\nc    11\nd    12\nName: col3...
```

Help would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['new'] = df['col3'].apply(str)
```

You can find lots of such methods in pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Answer (score 1):

try this once

```
df['new2'] = df['col3'].astype(str)
```

Comment: so, that works, and it technically answers the question, but i actually needed something more general. I can ask it in a different way though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i am sorry if i couldnt help you the way you wanted. :(

Comment: @mmvw - Faster is use `astype(str)` as `apply(str)`, so I think this is better solution.